# Proving equivalence of two definitions of "field"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, abelian-groups

Question 1: The multiplication axioms in the axiomatic definition of a "field" are NOT the same as saying "$(K\setminus \{ 0  \},\cdot )$" is an Abelian group" right?

Even though we can prove the definition "$(K,+), (K\setminus  \{ 0 \},\cdot )$ are Abelian groups, and Distributivity of multiplication over addition holds" is equivalent to the axiomatic definition of a field, the multiplication axioms for a field tell you what happen when you multiply any two elements, including 0, but $(K\setminus \{ 0 \},\cdot )$ being an Abelian group only tells you what happen when you multiply non-zero elements, so they are not the same right?

Question 2: To prove the more summarised definition (the one that only said $(K\setminus  \{ 0 \},\cdot )$ is Abelian) implies the multiplication axiom, we need the Distributivity axiom right?

To prove the two definitions are the same, if my reasoning above is correct, we need to know what happens when you multiply by 0 (something related to addition), and the only axiom connecting addition and multiplication is the Distributivity, so it's impossible to use something else to prove the equivalence of the definitions, right?

Side note. I proved the equivalence by proving $0 \cdot a = 0$ for all $a$ using Distributivity, then checked it implies all the axioms of multiplication for a "field" still hold even when we are multiplying by 0.

Comment: Can you please formulate *one* question *clearly*?

Comment: A field $K$ is a nonzero commutative ring, such that $(K^{\times},\cdot)$ is an abelian group. I see only one definition.

Comment: Yes, only the information that $(K,+)$ and $(K\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ are Abelian groups is not even telling if the function $\cdot$ is defined when one of the operands is $0$. Now, when you add "distributivity is holding" ... it depends how you write that. If it implicitly claims that $a\cdot (b+c)$ is defined for all $a,b,c\in K$, then we get that $\cdot$ is defined for $0$. The property $0\cdot a=0$ can be deduced.

Comment: @AnneBauval I have formulated my original question into question 1, and added a question 2.

Comment: Your Q1 is not clear because you don't say what you mean by "the multiplication axioms". Same problem with Q2: what is your "more summarized definition"? Like Dietrich Burde in the second comment, I only see one definition so I don't know which "two definitions" should be "the same".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm going to try to clarify your question before i give the answer to my interpretation of it...*

A field (F,+,x) is often either defined using 9 axioms or by simply saying:

- $(F,+)$ and $(F\setminus\{0\},x)$ are abelian groups
- x distributes over +

It is true that in the 9 axioms definition of a field (F,+,x), the properties of multiplication are a bit stronger than the ones you would get by stating "(F*,x) abelian group".

Indeed, in (F,+,x), field axioms on multiplication read as follows:

$\forall a, b, c\in F: a(bc)=(ab)c$

$\exists 1 \in F^* | \forall a \in F : 1a = a1 = a$

$\forall a \in F^* : \exists a' \in F^* | a'a = aa' = 1$

$\forall a, b, \in F : ab = ba$

these axioms are similar to saying "(F*,x) is an abelian group", but are stronger as they sometimes consider the whole field F instead of only F*.

To finally answer your question, **yes, the two definitions are completely equivalent**. And i would note that it is a good exercise to try and show this. It will reinforce your understanding of this algebraic structure.

Comment: To prove the equivalence, we only need to show $0 \cdot a=a$ for all $a$ right?

Comment: @HIH to be thorough i'd show that $0$'s are associative and commutative and finally that $0\times 1= 0\times 1 = 0$ (it all trivially follows from the definition of $0$, which is the identity of the field addition)

Comment: Why do we need to know "0's are associative"? Also, what do you mean by "0's are associative"?

Comment: @HIH i mean that the first axiom in my answer should be shown to hold when a,b,c come from F instead of F*. and that means when a or b or c are 0

Comment: "Indeed, in (F,+,x), field axioms on multiplication read as follows: [...] are stronger as they sometimes consider the whole field F instead of only F*." No, fields axioms are simply what you recalled at the beginning of your answer, and from this one easily deduces $\forall x\in F\quad 0x=x0=0$. I don't think there is more to say.

Comment: [There is nothing more to say because] all the additional tasks you mentionned (associativity and commutativity even when a or b or c is 0, and $0\times 1= 0\times 1 = 0$) are immediate consequences of $\forall x\in F\quad 0x=x0=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions remains unclear but they seem to boil down to:

let $(K,+,\cdot,0,1)$ be a (commutative) field, i.e. $(K,+,0)$ and $(K\setminus\{0\},\cdot,1)$ are abelian groups and $\cdot:K\times K\to K$ is distributive over $+$, does this imply that $\forall x\in K\quad x\cdot0=0\cdot x=0$?

and the answer is: yes (classical exercise).